# What's the difference between 'allow for' and 'for'?

Tags: grammar

> We erase the memory to allow for a peaceful transition.

(This is a sentence in a movie that I watched.)

> We erase the memory for a peaceful transition.

(I think maybe it is also right.)

What's the difference between those 2 sentences?

Is the 2nd sentence wrong?

Comment: It's your job to explain what you think the difference might be, then to make and then to justify your choice, and only then to ask what anyone else thinks…

Comment: What is "memory for a peaceful transition"?